# Deployed Shiny app giving 'curl' error

Tags: r, curl, shiny, shiny-server

I just deployed a `Shiny` app in shinyapps.io.

When I click the link it gives me a `disconnected from the server`.

I went to the app log (below) and it shows an error with `curl`, but the app runs perfectly locally. The app pulls .json data from the web.

Any idea what this could be?

```
2017-07-24T00:41:20.602891+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2017-07-24T00:41:20.602892+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.602893+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     filter, lag
2017-07-24T00:41:20.602894+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.603948+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2017-07-24T00:41:20.603950+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2017-07-24T00:41:20.603951+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.603949+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759622+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759625+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: Attaching package: ‘lubridate’
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759626+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759961+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769217+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759961+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     date
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759962+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769218+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: Attaching package: ‘chron’
2017-07-24T00:41:20.759960+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769218+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769542+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.775160+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: Warning: Error in : Required package curl not found. Please run: install.packages('curl')
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769541+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769543+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: 
2017-07-24T00:41:20.769542+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     days, hours, minutes, seconds, years
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778990+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778991+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     64: base::stop
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778992+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     62: value[[3L]]
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778991+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     63: stop
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778992+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     61: tryCatchOne
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778993+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     60: tryCatchList
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778993+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     59: tryCatch
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778994+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     58: loadpkg
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778994+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     57: fromJSON
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778995+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     55: eval
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778994+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     56: as.data.frame
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778996+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     54: eval
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778996+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     53: withVisible
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778997+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     52: source
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778997+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     13: runApp
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778998+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     12: fn
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778998+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778998+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778999+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      9: tryCatchList
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778999+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      8: tryCatch
2017-07-24T00:41:20.778999+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      7: connect$retry
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779000+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      6: eval
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779000+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      5: eval
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779000+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      4: eval
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779001+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      3: eval
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779001+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      2: eval.parent
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779001+00:00 shinyapps[198984]:      1: local
2017-07-24T00:41:20.779086+00:00 shinyapps[198984]: Error : Required package curl not found. Please run: install.packages('curl')
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by calling the `curl` library and then re-deploying the app.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add following in you script

```
options(rsconnect.http = "rcurl")
```